# How can I track the reopen votes / reopen status of my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I have [posted a question](https://superuser.com/q/730840/260802). It got closed. I edited it to get it to be reopened. Now I am not sure if my edits are sufficient.

How can I track the reopen votes for my question?  Is there a way to differentiate between "My edits are not good enough to get the question reopened" and "Nobody reviewed my question in the reopen review queue yet"?

Comment: Not an answer, but when you have 250 rep, you can see the close & reopen votes on your own question (as well as cast close/reopen votes on your own questions(, so at that point you will be able to get some idea of what has happened.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Is there a reason, why I should not see the close & reopen votes on my own question if I have a rep. lower than 250?

Comment: @AloisHeimer I don't have a really good answer to that, it is just one of the privileges that comes with more rep.  Viewing the votes is tied to the privileges of actually being able to vote, and that is really the limiting factor as most low rep users do not understand the site well enough to vote properly on their own posts.